# Encoded using Base 64 using UTF-8 for German umlauts( ä, ö, ü) in java, will atob() work or need any special handling

Tags: java, angular

Reading the  ä, ö, ü characters from message*.properties file
and using below code to send to client

```java
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Client is reading the data using `atob` method. (Angular application)

```js
const decodedString = atob(encodedString)
```

Will this work or need to do any special handling at client side, i.e. `atob` method?

Also does atob() mehtod use any default characterset?

please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section 'unicode strings' in the [MDN docs on btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) which clearly states: **No**, that does not work. `atob` and `btoa` are essentially broken as designed and should never be used except for utterly unlikely exotic scenarios (such as: You've BASE64ed some *ASCII* which is rather rare).

You probably want `b64_to_utf8` and `utf8_to_b64` instead.

Separately, java's own properties file format is not neccessarily entirely clear on encoding either. It's quite the chain - any error anywhere in it causes problems!

1. You create that `.properties` file with something, perhaps a text editor. Text editors edit text, files are bytes - so *somebody* is doing some charset conversion. **Ensure editor is using UTF-8**.
2. In java, you usually read properties file using the rather broken `java.util.Properties` class. It's 30 years old and has all sorts of warts. In particular, if you use the `Properties.load(InputStream)` variant, which is the commonly used one, e.g:

```java
try (var in = new FileInputStream("my.properties")) {
  properties.load(in);
}
```

**you broke it** - that will read as ISO8859. You must *first* convert your InputStream to a reader:

```java
try (var in = new FileInputStream("my.properties")) {
  properties.load(new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

3. You then fetch the bytes and Base64 encode them. You have to use `.getBytes(UTF_8)` or you break it unless the platform default encoding is UTF-8. Fortunately, you're already doing that.
4. You then send the Base64 bytes across the pipe. Nobody is applying any encodings here (or, rather, it'll convert back and forth loads of times, but given that base64 is all 'safe ascii', this is highly unlikely to cause any issues).
5. The base64 arrives in your javascript code. If you use btoa, you break it. You have to use b64_to_utf8. Finally you've "arrived" - a string with the right characters in your javascript environment.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

b64_to_utf8 using escape function which is deprectated(not fully according to documentation). can I still use the same or need to use different method.
**
function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
}

Comment: try it and see, right?

Comment: Yes. It's working now. thank you.
But one thing is, can we replace **escape** function with any other function, as it is deprecated( not fully)